Admin JS Ajax call in the Controller
I am trying to get the response of my Ajax in the Controller :
require(['jquery', 'mage/url', 'mage/cookies'], function ($, url) {
    'use strict';

    window.updateStatus = function (element) {
        var isEnabled = $(element).val();
        var entityId = $(element).data('entity-id');
        var formKey = $.mage.cookies.get('form_key'); // Get the form key

        console.log('Form Key:', formKey);
        console.log(url.build('customergroup/index/updatetoggle'));
// Log the form key to ensure it's being retrieved

        $.ajax({
            // url: url.build('customergroup/index/updatetoggle'),
            url: url.build(window.BASE_URL + 'customergroup/index/updatetoggle'),


            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                entity_id: entityId,
                is_enabled: isEnabled,
                form_key: formKey
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    console.error('Error:', response.message);
                    alert(response.message);
                } else {
                    console.log('Status updated successfully', response);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Error updating status', error);
            }
        });
    };
});

Controller File :
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;

class Updatetoggle extends Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

   

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $responseData = ['success' => false];

        try {
            // Validate form key
            if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.'));
            }

            if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid request.'));
            }

            $entityId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
            $isEnabled = $this->getRequest()->getParam('is_enabled');

            $this->logger->info("Toggle updated for Entity ID: $entityId, Enabled: $isEnabled");

            $responseData['success'] = true;
            $responseData['entity_id'] = $entityId;
            $responseData['is_enabled'] = $isEnabled;

        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $responseData['error'] = true;
            $responseData['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $responseData['error'] = true;
            $responseData['message'] = __('An error occurred while updating the status.');
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $result->setData($responseData);
    }
}

Block File :
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\View\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;

class EnableToggle extends AbstractRenderer
{
    /**
     * Render the HTML for the enable/disable toggle.
     *
     * @param DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        // Ensure the 'is_enabled' field exists in your data source
        $isEnabled = (bool) $row->getData('is_enabled');
        $entityId = $row->getId();

        // Build the select element
        $html = '<select class="admin__control-select" data-entity-id="' . $entityId . '" onchange="updateStatus(this)">';
        $html .= '<option value="1"' . ($isEnabled ? ' selected' : '') . '>Enabled</option>';
        $html .= '<option value="0"' . (!$isEnabled ? ' selected' : '') . '>Disabled</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';

        return $html;
    }
}

routes.xml :
The response is in the ajax but not coming in the Controller.

As i can see you want to send data to your admin controller
but using this in your ajax will send data to front controller because BASE_URL doesn't give path to admin so you should try updating
url.build(window.BASE_URL + 'customergroup/index/updatetoggle')

TO
url.build(window.BASE_URL + 'Your Admin Route Here/customergroup/index/updatetoggle')

See network tab to check either it goes to proper route or not!!
Hope it helps!
feel free to reach out to me in case of any other queries..
If it solved your problem kindly mark this answer as accepted!
